# volume control does not show with <audio> tag

Tags: html5-audio

Volume control does not show with `<audio>` tag;

CODE:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="music/My_Love_Song_Forever.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <br><a href='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/' title='Get Quicktime' onclick='window.open(this.href); return false'>Install Quicktime<\/a> to enjoy this beautiful! Love Song!
</audio>
```

PICTURE:

[image]

BTW, if this were a .mov file, the controls do show a volume adjust. NOT with .mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

Found this goodie about 10 minutes later ... nevertheless, I thought the answer may be of use to someone else as well.

[image]

Reference:

https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/issues/499

BTW, here is their magic potion:

```
audio {
    display: block;

    width:    300px;
    margin:   20px;
}
```

Why can't the powers to be just
 add these parts to the list?